# DESCRIBE a joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

If I use

```
DESCRIBE 'tablename'
```

I get all the filednames, which is what I need.
But is it possible to get the fieldnames in the same way if I have joined one or more tables?

Comment: What do you mean by `joined` table?

Comment: You could create a VIEW and DESCRIBE the view.

Comment: DESCRIBE the view is not the solution.Not working.
You will not get fields of JOINED tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you describe table -> you actually get table's fieldnames. (it cannot know which table you want to join it with, and can hardly read minds)
As said in a comment, you can create a View, that is returning fields with joined tables, and try to describe the view itself.